# Why in the concrete decorator's constructor I have to repeat code of the superclass constructor?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, decorator, superclass

was trying to implement the Decorator pattern - for simplicity in this example we only have 1 concrete decorator named ConcreteDecorator1 and I got it to work, the example in functional. However my question is around OOP and more specifically I don't understand why I was getting a "component is null" exception on this line of the ConcreteDecorator1 : `myField = this.myField + component.Operation();`  BEFORE adding `this.component = component` in the constructor of the same class?
I mean `this.component = component` happens in the c-tor of the super class (Decorator) so why wasn't that enough?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        
        var cc = new ConcreteComponent();
        cc.Operation();
        Console.WriteLine(cc.myField);

        var cd1 = new ConcreteDecorator1(cc);
        cd1.Operation();
        Console.WriteLine(cd1.myField);

        var cd2 = new ConcreteDecorator1(cd1);
        cd2.Operation();
        Console.WriteLine(cd2.myField);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}



abstract class Component
{

    public int myField;
    public virtual int Operation()
    {
        return myField;
    }
}

class ConcreteComponent : Component
{
    public override int Operation()
    {
        myField = 22;
        return myField;
    }
}

class Decorator : Component
{
    private Component component;
    public Decorator(Component component)
    {
        this.component = component;
    }
}

class ConcreteDecorator1 : Decorator
{
    private Component component;
    public ConcreteDecorator1(Component component) : base(component)
    {
        this.component = component; // WHY IS THIS LINE NECESSARY HERE? Don't we have it in the constructor of the base class, Decorator?
    }
    public override int Operation()
    {
        myField = 100;
        myField = this.myField + component.Operation(); // error on this line: component was null ...  UNLESS WE ADD this.component = component; in the c-tor WHy was this necessary? Doesn't the super class c-tor take care of it?
        return myField;
    }
}
```

So bottom line: why in the concrete decorator's constructor I have to repeat code of the superclass constructor? I thought I could leave it as this:

```
public ConcreteDecorator1(Component component) : base(component)
{
}
```

and potentially add in the body something extra, like additional logic, if needed (not needed here but just saying).

Later edit - Another working variant (Variant2):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var cc = new ConcreteComponent();
            cc.Operation();
            Console.WriteLine(cc.myField);

            var cd1 = new ConcreteDecorator1(cc);
            cd1.Operation();
            Console.WriteLine(cd1.myField);

            var cd2 = new ConcreteDecorator1(cd1);
            cd2.Operation();
            Console.WriteLine(cd2.myField);

        }
    }

    abstract class Component
    {

        public int myField;
        public virtual int Operation()
        {
            return myField;
        }
    }

    class ConcreteComponent : Component
    {
        public override int Operation()
        {
            myField = 22;
            return myField;
        }
    }

    class Decorator : Component
    {
        public Component Component { get; set; }
        
    }

    class ConcreteDecorator1 : Decorator
    {
        public ConcreteDecorator1(Component component) 
        {
            this.Component = component; 
        }
        public override int Operation()
        {
            myField = 100;
            myField = this.myField + this.Component.Operation(); 
            return myField;
        }
    }
```

Still not great, because I would rather define the Operation in the Decorator and in the concrete decorator I would just set the myField value...

Variant 3 (later update, also works):

```
abstract class Component
{
    protected int myField;
    public virtual int Operation()
    {
        return this.myField;
    }
}

class ConcreteComponent : Component
{
    public ConcreteComponent(int myField)
    {
        this.myField = myField;
    }
}

class Decorator : Component
{
    protected Component component;
    public Decorator(Component component)
    {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public override int Operation()
    {
        this.myField = this.myField + component.Operation();
        return myField;
    }
}

class ConcreteDecorator1 : Decorator
{
    public ConcreteDecorator1(Component component) : base(component)
    {
        this.myField = 100;
    }

}

class ConcreteDecorator2 : Decorator
{
    public ConcreteDecorator2(Component component) : base(component)
    {
        this.myField = 1000;
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var cc = new ConcreteComponent(22);
        Console.WriteLine(cc.Operation());

        //var cd1 = new ConcreteDecorator(cc, 100);
        //cd1.Operation();
        //Console.WriteLine(cd1.myField);

        var cd2 = new ConcreteDecorator1(cc);
        Console.WriteLine(cd2.Operation());

        var cd3 = new ConcreteDecorator2(cd2);
        Console.WriteLine(cd3.Operation());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you made `component` a `private` field erroneously, when you should have used a `protected` property, like `protected Component Component { get: }` in order for it to be usable in child classes. The double definition of `component` is *also* wrong. Perhaps read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: Thank Camilo, I know the access modifiers in theory but oop related stuff is best exemplified on practical examples like this. What do you mean by double definition of component, sorry

Comment: `component` is doubly-defined, `Decorator.component` and `ConcreteDecorator1.component`. Normally, `ConcreteDecorator1` would use the `Component` that `Decorator` exposes

Comment: With this code you only set the component of the parent class, not the component of this class. And when this code is executed myField = this.myField + component.Operation (); The program gives a null error.

Comment: You do not need to use this.myField. The keyword this is for when you have the name of the parent field in the child class. this correct : myField = 1000;

Comment: There was no problem with your code other than the explanation I gave. This link and see a real example: https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to redefine a common object `private Component component;`. Change the double definition of component as follows

```
class Decorator : Component
{
   public Component component;
   public Decorator(Component component)
   {
      this.component = component;
   }
}

class ConcreteDecorator1 : Decorator
{
   public ConcreteDecorator1(Component component) : base(component)
   {
           
   }
   public override int Operation()
   {
      myField = 100;
      myField = this.myField + component.Operation(); // error on this line: component was null ...  UNLESS WE ADD this.component = component; in the c-tor WHy was this necessary? Doesn't the super class c-tor take care of it?
      return myField;
   }
}
```

With this code you only set the component of the parent class, not the component of this class. And when this code is executed `myField = this.myField + component.Operation ();` The program gives a null error.

```
public ConcreteDecorator1(Component component) : base(component)
{
    //This is wrong because the component is never set      
}
```

Suppose you have two variables called x. You define one globally and the other locally within a function. You must use this keyword when you want to access the global variable.

see this example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        math m = new math();
        m.cc();
        m.dd();
    }
    class math
    {
        private int x = 100;
        public int pp(out int disX)
        {
            int x = 200;
            disX = this.x;
            return x;
        }

        public void cc()
        {
            int x = 50;
            Console.WriteLine(x);      //answer: 50
            Console.WriteLine(this.x); //answer: 100
        }

        public void dd()
        {
            int t;
            Console.WriteLine(pp(out t));    // answer: 200
            Console.WriteLine(t);            //answer: 100
        }
    }
```

Comment: `public` fields is almost always a bad idea, that should be a property instead, and I'm pretty certain it shouldn't be `public` at all, but rather `protected`

Comment: so would you use a protected field or a property for myField, Camilo? I got it to work for a public field... Thank you both!

Comment: Yes you can use protected

Comment: What do you think about my Variant3, edited my original post, it's at the end ? Do you find any faults to it standard-wise? (And it worked with `public ConcreteDecorator1(Component component) : base(component)
   {
           // nothing here
   }` (I assume this worked because I used protected fields, right?)

Comment: `class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Person(int age = 10)
        {
            this.Age = age;
        }
    }

    class Customer : Person
    {
        public Customer(int age) : base(age)
        {
            // this.Age = age;
        }
    }`

Comment: I still don't get why I have to set the component there. How is that different from my example above, where I don't necessarily have to add `this.Age = age;` in the ctor of the subclass...

Comment: You should be careful in using the word this. I put a description in the post with an example. If necessary, tell me another use of this keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also your link to dofactory was extremely useful, meysam! And camilo, thanks for the link, lots of basic stuff I never stopped to think about in correlation with scenarios related to derived classes. Powerful.